# How change in one project JIRA Ticket reflect the linked ticket in other project

Tags: jira, jira-plugin

We have different projects for the developers based on their area & QA has a separate project on JIRA.

1. The web has one project say 'Web.
2. The mobile app has another project say 'Mobile'
3. QA team maintaining 'QA' project and QA Team will create the tickets and link to the original tickets in Web and Mobile.

As of now, QA Team manually tracking the original tickets and once the original ticket moved to 'In QA', will start work on the QA Ticket and change the status to 'In Progress'. Once testing completed moves the QA ticket to 'DONE' and the original ticket to 'Resolved'.

Now, I want to know, is there any way that we can automate this process. Suppose when the original ticket moved to 'In QA' linked QA ticket must be moved to 'To Do' from 'In Dev'. Once the QA ticket moved to 'DONE', the original ticket must be moved to 'Resolved'.

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of jira plugins to help you automate this process exactly as you describe it. Personally I like powerscripts from cPrime a lot since it is really easy to learn and still quite powerfull.

https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/43318/power-scripts-for-jirascript-automation?hosting=server&tab=overview